# Is there Python programming to connect to the ssid of a router without using CMD?

Tags: python

Is there Python programming to connect to the ssid of a router without using CMD?

I have programming working that runs cmd batch files or sends "netsh" commands to the cmd window.
CMD is an excellent debugging tool but I can't believe it was intended to be used seriously for using with own software programming as the cmd editor needs to open, be opened or flash every time a command is sent.

It might help to mention that the stick PC I'm using does not have a physical monitor attached but with a hardware adaption to the HDMI output and VNC software installed so the screen can be viewed on any other computer with a VNC viewer. Mouse and keyboard can also control the PC stick with VNC server running.

As the VNC server will not be active until the Windows 10 has installed itself; precautions such as disabling Automatic Repair at start up, Windows Updates paused or anything else in start up that would require what, will be unseen, requests for mouse clicks or keyboard presses.

It needs programming to connect to a portable router, passively poll the connection to see if the router is still connected and reconnect whenever possible. Without Using CMD.

I have had all this working for a while. It's proving reliable to connect and run but not comfortable to watch because the batch file which loops every 10 minutes uses

```
netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME interface="WIRELESS NETWORK CONNECTION"
```

and

```
'name="name_of_wifi" interface="type_of_network_interface" priority=1'
```

It keeps opening CMD window and the reconnection first closes the VNC server so on the VNC client the VNC viewer has to be started again.

I haven't used Python yet but before I do I want to know if there is programming and/or libraries available to connect to the ssid of a wifi router without CMD.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: The builtin `subprocess` module should do what you want. i.e., calling `subprocess.run(['netsh', 'wlan', 'ssid=', 'name=', 'interface='])` without opening a cmd instance.

Comment: or the builtin `subprocess and `shlex` modules: `subprocess.run(shelx.split("command as string"))`